# How to query schemas in gsettings?

Tags: debian, mate-desktop, gsettings

When I do

```
$ gsettings list-schemas
```

I get lot of schemas but I am interested only in looking through schemas starting with

```
org.mate.$something
```

basically all schemas which have to do with MATE but there doesn't seem to be a way. The manpage doesn't have any examples.

I did try to do it blind like

```
$ gsettings list-schemas org.mate.*
Usage:
  gsettings [--schemadir SCHEMADIR] list-schemas [--print-paths]

List the installed (non-relocatable) schemas

Arguments:
  SCHEMADIR A directory to search for additional schemas
```

can somebody suggest a better way?

To be more precise -

If I do -

```
$ gsettings list-schemas | wc -l
217
```

I have 217 schemas as of this writing, of this some will be like

```
org.mate.Marco.general
```

and there may be others such as -

```
org.gnome.desktop.background
```

OR

```
ca.desrt.dconf-editor.Demo.Conflict1
```

which I am not interested in atm.

I need a way to grep through the schemas without exposing any keys.

A dirty way is doing is -

```
$ gsettings list-keys org.mate. <TAB key>
Display all 132 possibilities? (y or n)
```

but I am guessing there is a better way.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your question correctly, but have you tried `gsettings list-recursively | grep -i mate`?

Comment: The problem with that you command/code is that you get too much info. I just need info. on the top schemas only and then drill down on the schema/s I am interested in . I have made the question a bit more precise so hopefully it make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return the `mate` schemas in the top level only.

```
gsettings list-schemas | grep ^org.mate
```

Comment: It would be better to use `gsettings list-schemas | grep ^org\.mate` or with `grep ^org[.]mate`. Though I _do_ doubt you'll have schemas beginning with something like `orgzmate` or `org-mate`, these edge/corner cases can make for difficult debugging.